# Twig check if date is christmas or easter

Tags: symfony, date, twig

I got three versions of the application logo, one for each days, one for easter and one for christmas.

I would like to make a function that automatically change logo in certain period of the year but not bugging me changing every year the date.

Here is current code:

```
    <img id="app_logo" src="
         {% if date("2019-12-10 00:00:00") < date() and date("2019-12-26 23:59:59") > date() %}
                {{ asset('img/home/logo-white-christmas.png')}}
         {% elseif date("2019-04-10 00:00:00") < date() and date("2019-04-28 23:59:25") > date %}
                {{ asset('img/home/logo-white-easter.png')}}
         {% else %}
                {{ asset('img/home/logo-white.png')}}
         {% endif %}
    " class="img-fluid" style="max-width:280px"/>
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: I'd suggest extending `twig` with a filter instead of trying to hardcode this inside the template itself though...

Answer (score 0):

I think it's helps you, so if you don't want to change year any years you can just try to check the day and month

```html
{% set now = date() %}

{% if  now | date('d-m') >= '10-12' and now | date('d-m') <= '26-12' %}
  <img id="app_logo" src="{{ asset('img/home/logo-white-christmas.png')}}" class="img-fluid" style="max-width:280px"/> 
{% elseif now | date('d-m') >= '10-04' and now | date('d-m') <= '28-04' %}
  <img id="app_logo" src="{{ asset('img/home/logo-white-easter.png')}}" class="img-fluid" style="max-width:280px"/>
{% else %}
  <img id="app_logo" src="{{ asset('img/home/logo-white.png')}}" class="img-fluid" style="max-width:280px"/>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: That will work for Christmas but Easter is based on a lunar cycle.   Hard coding specific date ranges  is not going to do the trick.

Comment: Yes it's true but I'm try just to debug the code showed

Comment: Why do not you use an API that will allow you to recover all vacation dates exemple => https://holidayapi.com/

Comment: @Heyden7611 you can put your answer but don’t be just spectator my friend

Answer (score 0):

For recup Date =>

```
$hapi = new HolidayAPI\v1('_YOUR_API_KEY_');

$parameters = array(
  // Required
  'country' => 'US',
  'year'    => 2016,
  // Optional
  // 'month'    => 7,
  // 'day'      => 4,
  // 'previous' => true,
  // 'upcoming' => true,
  // 'public'   => true,
  // 'pretty'   => true,
);

$response = $hapi->holidays($parameters);
```

[Api holiday](https://github.com/joshtronic/php-holidayapi)

Create an entity to store the date in BDD and you could also create a Twig Extension that would compare today's date with the holiday dates

Answer (score 0):

If you have the calendar extension enabled for your PHP installation (often it already will be), you have access to [easter_date()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.easter-date.php) and [easter_days()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.easter-days.php). So you could do something like this:

```
$easterSunday = easter_date();
$oneDayInSeconds = 24 * 60 * 60;
$showEasterLogoStart = $easterSunday - 7 * $oneDayInSeconds;
$showEasterLogoEnd = $easterSunday + 5 * $oneDayInSeconds;
$now = time();
$showEasterLogo = $showEasterLogoStart <= $now || $showEasterLogoEnd >= $now;
```

You could pass this to your twig or make it available as a twig extension.

Note that `easter_date()` does not use the PHP timezone setting, but the `TZ` environment variable. You could either set it or use `easter_days()` instead. A work-around can be found in the documentation itself as well.